# Nginx configuration to make open ports look like they're closed

Tags: nginx

I have ports 443 and 80 open on my firewall and pointing to my Nginx reverse-proxy server. I have Nginx setup so that if anyone accesses ports 443 or 80 using my IP address Nginx returns a 444 error. I would like to set Nginx up in such a way so that if someone does a port scan of my IP address they won't even see the ports as open. Is this something that's possible? My current config looks like this:

```
server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443 ssl;
  
  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /path/to/crt;
  ssl_certificate_key /path/to/crt/key;

  server_name _;
  return 444;
}
```

I'd like to change this so that nothing gets returned and the client just gets a timeout error with no HTTP headers transferred.

Comment: What is the rule for allowing requests to be made? Auth? IP? URI? Whenever you need something from the client, it's probably going to know a connection is possible.

Comment: A firewall can do that, then you won't need  nginx anymore. The brits say you can't have your cake and eat it, although they often try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"I have ports 443 and 80 open on my firewall and pointing to my Nginx reverse-proxy server. I have Nginx setup so that if anyone accesses ports 443 or 80"

So your firewall is useless: every 80/443 request "travel" through the firewall as if it were not there.

You cannot prevent anyone from seeing that ports are open, unless you program your firewall to allow connections only (for example) from certain source IPs.

In this case you could impose rules like "ONLY if a connection comes from my home IP allow it to get to ports 443 and 80, otherwise block them"

Comment: Don't open the ports for the public? Easy! Change ever `listen 80` to `listen 127.0.0.1:80` also the same for 443 and your issues are gone. The web is secured from You and your Webservice ;) And you don't need to open any firewall ports. Seriously, move your question, to superuser as you seems to me not a business Admin